# Cuda: An illegal instruction was encountered when accessing structure

Tags: cuda

If I run the following program I get "an illegal instruction was encountered". The program accesses an array of unsigned long longs.

Error: ../file.cu(43) : CUDA Runtime API error 73: an illegal instruction was encountered.

GPU: GTX 760

Cuda 6.5 (V6.5.16). The error happens only when running the code in the Release mode (-O3 optimization flag).

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

typedef unsigned long long ul;

static inline void __checkCudaErrors(cudaError err, const char *file, const int line )
{
    if(cudaSuccess != err){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s(%i) : CUDA Runtime API error %d: %s.\n",file, line, (int)err, cudaGetErrorString( err ) );
        exit(-1);
    }
}
#define checkCuda(err)  __checkCudaErrors (err, __FILE__, __LINE__)


__global__ void testReadOnly(ul *A)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x/32;
    A=A+(32*i);
    atomicCAS(A+threadIdx.x, 0ull, 0ull);
}
int main(void)
{
    ul *d_A = NULL;
    int size = 32*sizeof(ul);
    checkCuda(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_A, size));
    checkCuda(cudaMemset(d_A, (int)0, size));
    testReadOnly<<<1, 32>>>(d_A);
    checkCuda(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    checkCuda(cudaFree(d_A));
    checkCuda(cudaDeviceReset());
    return 0;
}
```

PTX code: _Z12testReadOnlyPy:

```
MOV R1, c[0x0][0x44]
S2R R0, SR_TID.X
MOV R4, c[0x0][0x140]
LOP.AND R3, R0, -0x20
MOV R8, RZ
IADD R2.CC, R3, R0
ISET.LT.AND R0, R3, RZ, PT

IADD.X R0, R0, RZ
SHL R3, R0, 0x3
MOV R9, RZ
IMAD.U32.U32 R4.CC, R2, 0x8, R4
IMAD.U32.U32.HI R0, R2, 0x8, R3
IADD.X R5, R0, c[0x0][0x144]
ATOM.E.CAS.U64 RZ, [R4], R8, RZ
```

Comment: What CUDA and host compiler version are you using? This certainly looks like a compiler bug to me

Comment: I tried with `atomicCAS(((ul*)(A+i)->data)+threadIdx.x, 0ull, 0ull);`, the error still happens. I added the cuda version to the question.

Comment: The obvious suggestion is try CUDA 7 and see if the problem persists. If so, raise a bug report with NVIDIA

Comment: I updated the code, now there are no structures involved. Currently I don't have access to CUDA 7. When I have I'll try to check this again.

Comment: I agree with @talonmies that it appears to be a bug.  I have tested (the previous code with structures) on both CUDA 6.5 and CUDA 7.0 (on linux) and the behavior is reproducible (on cc3.0/3.5; on cc2.0 I am not able to repro).  I have filed a bug with NVIDIA (in case you haven't/don't).  I don't have any further information at this time.

Comment: I've added a short community wiki answer. If someone cares to upvote it, this question will be removed from the unanswered list....

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a compiler bug in the CUDA 6.5 and 7.0 release toolkit which effects code generation for compute capability 3.0/3.5 devices. A bug report was raised with NVIDIA.

[This answer was assembled from comments and added as a community wiki entry to get this question off the unanswered list]